# Will 23.04 to 24.04 need 23.10 in between?

Tags: upgrade, 22.04, 23.04, 23.10

I'm running 23.04 and recently got the popup saying there will be no more security updates. Since the long term 24.04 is just a couple of months away my plan was just to wait for 24.04, since every update can cause issues.

But as I think of it, if the only update to 24.04 from 23.04 will require the 23.10 first, I guess I might as well do it sooner than later.

What is know about the update paths/requirements to 24.04 from various earlier versions?

Comment: The upgrade path is 23.04 -> 23.10 -> 24.04. You have to upgrade every 6 months.

Comment: No *Quality Assurance* testing is done on the 23.04 to 24.04 upgrade as it's **unsupported** and thus no need. I've non-destructively re-installed systems with Ubuntu *noble* as I don't need to keep 23.04 (*already having 23.10 systems*) where you could do that in the future (*that's unsupported now too*) but you'd be *unsafe* now until that is done as your system isn't getting any security fixes now, so keep your system offline until you *release-upgrade* [to 23.10] or re-install.